# Scrolling Background-Image Parallax with background-position: bottom

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm using the jQuery code below to create a parallax effect on the header areas in a WordPress site. I found the code on here and have amended it to work on my site and deal with the offset caused by my navbar. In the below code the background-image is positioned from the top. However, I've now been asked if the background-position can be set to bottom and the parallax effect can scroll up from there. I can tweak the CSS to make it **background-position: 50% bottom** initially but as soon as you start scrolling the position starts offsetting from the top again. Can anybody help? I'm much better at CSS than I am at jQuery and have been trying to find a solution for many hours now to no avail.

Webpage where the code is being used can be found here https://thamesenterprisepark.com/staging/index.php/about/

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // The function
        var background_image_parallax = function($object, multiplier){
          multiplier = typeof multiplier !== 'undefined' ? multiplier : 0.5;
            multiplier = 1 - multiplier;
          var $doc = $(document);
          $object.css({"background-attatchment" : "fixed"});
            $(window).scroll(function(){
              var from_top = $doc.scrollTop() + -90,
                  bg_css = '50% '+(multiplier * from_top) + 'px';
              $object.css({"background-position" : bg_css });
          });
        };
    
        //Just pass the jQuery object
        background_image_parallax($(".box2"));
    
        //optional second value for speed
        background_image_parallax($(".hentry.has-post-thumbnail"));
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a great deal of trial and error I think I've found a solution. I changed this line of code to make the multiplier negative

```
multiplier = 0 - multiplier;
```

Changed this line of code to remove the offset for the navbar as it's no longer required and now leaves a gap at the top

```
  var from_top = $doc.scrollTop(),
```

And changed this line of code to include the css offset for the background position, to allow it to be offset from the bottom. I've been trying to do this for a while but couldn't work out the correct syntax.

```
bg_css = 'left 50% bottom '+(multiplier * from_top) + 'px';
```

Need to test, cross browser and cross device but it's doing the trick so far.